# How to convert this cycle into Linq.js or just linq

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, linq.js

My code is written in JavaScript

```
for (var i = 0; i < tsUA.length; i++) {
        if (tsRU[i][0] === tsUA[i][0])
            tsUA[i][2] = tsRU[i][1];
        }
```

preferably using firstOrDefault

Comment: Show what you did in linq

Comment: I am new one with Linq and I would like to modify my code.
I tried to do so:
var tsRU = Enumerable.from(ru).select(kv => [kv.key, kv.value]).toArray();
var tsUA = Enumerable.from(ua).select(kv => [kv.key, kv.value]).toArray();

var qq = tsRU.firstOrDefault(q => q === tsUA).toArray();

Comment: I don't think your code would benefit from being converted to linq.  Because there are two arrays, you would still have to keep track of indexes.  It's fine as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# LINQ, you could do this:

```
var query = tsUA.Zip(tsRU, (ua, ru) => new { ua, ru })
    .Where(p => p.ua[0] == p.ru[0]);
foreach (var pair in query)
    pair.ua[2] = pair.rs[1];
```

Note, there isn't that much "LINQ" in here, you're modifying objects. LINQ is not designed to do that.  And your request to use `FirstOrDefault()` makes no sense, it has no place here.

As you should probably notice, you're not gaining much by using LINQ here.  Also, keeping your objects as arrays makes it less readable.  Why not create proper objects to represent your data?

Comment: You're right. The result is a little bit not be what I needed, but still substantially changed the situation. Thank you! 
In TypeScript it looks like this:
var query = tsUA.zip(tsRU, (ua, ru) => ({ ua: ua, ru: ru })).where(p => p.ua[0] === p.ru[0]).toArray();

query.forEach(pair => pair.ua[2] = pair.ru[1]);